# Direct show samples (AMCap) on Platform SDK with  MP4 file

Tags: visual-c++, directshow, mp4, muxer

I want to generate .mp4 file using Direct show samples (AMCap). But i don't know how to implement this.
Can anyone please help me about this?

Thanks in advance,
Dhaval Kariya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AMCap Sample`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) captures and displays video. No encoding and choices of multiplexing into files (only basic capture/recording through a basically obsolete helper interface).

> Video capture application.
>
> This sample application demonstrates the following tasks related to
>   audio and video capture:
>
> - Capture to a file
> - Live preview
> - Allocation of the capture file
> - Display of device property pages
> - Device enumeration
> - Stream control

The items above might be confusing as they mention capture and file allocation. This is a trail of 15 years old history when file capture was a big deal. The helper object to initialize capture targets AVI and ASF/WMV only, you neither can extend it to support other formats, nor you need to.

You need to check how to store video/audio into files (see below) and follow the same steps in building the pipeline with MPEG-4 encoders and multiplexer. You will need to use a third party MPEG-4 multiplexer for `MP4` file format because Windows does not provide you with such out-of-the-box usable component.

See:

- [Capturing Video to a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318628%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Free DirectShow Mpeg-4 Filters](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/)

Comment: Hey, thanks Roman for your reply. I have looked into http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/ and downloaded the source as well as dll files. I am beginner of video capture and vc++ programming. I don't know how to use MP4 mux and demux with AMCap Sample. so can you please give me a sample code with bit description. Thanks in advance, Dhaval Kariya

Comment: I suggest that you make yourself familiar with GraphEdit tool in Windows SDK. It is described on MSDN here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx You can build DirectShow graphs interactively, and you then will do a similar thing in software. You will be able to see how to attach MP4 mux to the data being captured live.

Comment: Thank You Roman. I finally got bit knowledge to use GraphEdit tool.